# Silverlight ItemsControl formatting

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0

I have a ItemsControl in Silverlight to display a list of objects.  These objects contain the strings Name, Value and Unit such as "Load", "100" and "MW".  The control is within a grid column which can vary in size depending on the size of the browser window.  I am trying to format the DataTemplate to allow the Name string to be on the left with the Value and Unit to be on the right.  eg...

```
|Load      100 MW |
|Load2      50 MW |
|Unit1      20 X  |
|Unit2     130 YXZ|
```

After a lot of trial and error I have managed to get this to work by using a grid with two columns.  The left containing the name and the right containing a stack panel containing both the value and unit.  This seems to work but if there are any units which differ in length the alignment of the text doesn't work.  eg...

```
|Load       100 MW|
|Load2       50 MW|
|Unit1        20 X|
|Unit2     130 YXZ|
```

I'm running out of ideas on how to format this.  Can anyone suggest anything?  The main point is that I do not know in advance the length of the name, value or unit strings and, when the main column changes size, the name must stay on the left with the value and unit on the right.

Thanks in advance,  Cap

(here is the code so far)

```
<ItemsControl Name="DataTypesGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0,8,0,0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" Background="{x:Null}" IsEnabled="True">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,2,0,0" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="Auto">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,4,0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Unit}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you basically start again with each new row, calculating grid column widths based on a single data entry.

The problem is you want width behaviour that spans rows "just like a datagrid column". Sounds like you actually want to customise a datagrid instead and strip out any headings you don't want instead.

Some alternatives:

- Set a minimum width on your units box so that smaller units, at least, align.
- Calculate the actual width of the widest unit and apply that value to a width binding (used on all "units" textblocks)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  You're right, I'm pretty much after datagrid functionality, infact it was my first choice in this.  However when playing with the formatting I found it impossible to strip away all formatting and, more importantly, the option to select rows.  I need to it appear as normal text within the page as it's just one of a number of places where data is shown and I need it all to have the same format.

I may have to stick with the minimum width idea, though the calculation method does sound interesting.  I'll have to look into it.  Thanks :)